# Gradle Build Error - KMM Multiplatform-resources - dependency configuration ':shared:iosX64CInteropApiElements'

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

In KMM project , I am trying to [Moko Resources](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources).
**But getting Gradle Error

> Cannot change attributes of dependency configuration ':shared:iosX64CInteropApiElements' after it has been resolved.**

If someone has any resolution kindly provide.

Thanks in advance.

I checked & tried and googled lot to fix it but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Kotlin 1.9.0 that has yet to be resolved. I faced the same thing and have to stay on 1.8.22 for now. See https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources/issues/535

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).